# How to decide which evaluator is used by ExternalLanguage Cell for a particular language?

Tags: external-calls, external-language-cell

By default when I start an `ExternalLanguage` cell for `Shell` it starts `powershell.exe`.

Even though when I check my default system shell:

```
$SystemShell
```

it returns `cmd`.

```
FindExternalEvaluators["Shell"]
```

Show that for both `cmd.exe` and `powershell.exe` are available.

So my question is how do I decide which `ExternalEvaluator` is used by the `ExternalLanguage` cell when there is more than one evaluator present for that language?

---

Found a few functions but have not been able to solve the problem yet:

`` ExternalEvaluate`Private`$DefaultSession `` returns `Automatic` may be this value needs to be changed somehow to solve the problem?

`` ExternalEvaluate`FE`GetDefaultCellEvaluationLanguage[] `` returns `"Shell"` which makes sense since whenever I create a new `ExternalLanguage` cell by default it is of language type `"Shell"`.

`` ExternalEvaluate`GetDefaultExternalSession["Shell"] `` return `ExternalSessionObject` pointing to `powershell.exe`.

Comment: The code for this is in $InstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/Components/ExternalEvaluate_Shell. There's probably a stylesheet for the ExternalLanguage cell which controls the selection. And a variable called $SystemShell which chooses the default shell. I'd try changing the $SystemShell first. If that fails, you might try editing the code next, after making a backup. Or add a new shell paclet of your own, and edit the stylesheet to call it.

Comment: There must be a simple way of doing this without manipulating system files. WRI usually have functions in hidden contexts that can change these.

Comment: I just tried modifying $SystemShell, and it accepted /bin/bash in place of the default /bin/sh. I'm on Linux, so I can't test your case directly. There is some code in the evaluator which tests for Windows, and some code referencing the power shell, so you might want to do a quick review of the code, even if you don't want to modify anything.